# How to read document headers and lines from XML file by using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file which has document headers and lines(rows) which I want to read by using PHP.
I can read headers but the problem I have now is I cannot read lines

These are my XML tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GRPO>    
<Goods>
<CardCode>V10000</CardCode>
<DocDueDate>07/11/2016</DocDueDate>
<GoodsLines>
   <Line>
      <ItemNo>A00003</ItemNo>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>4000</UnitPrice>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <ItemNo>A00004</ItemNo>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>5000</UnitPrice>
   </Line>
</GoodsLines>
</Goods>        
</GRPO>
```

This is the PHP I tried to write in order to read the XML file

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("GRPO.xml");

foreach($xml->children() as $Goods)
{
echo"CardCode: $Goods->CardCode";
echo"DocDueDate: $Goods->DocDueDate";

foreach($xml->children() as $Line)
{
echo"ItemNo: $Line->ItemNo";
echo"Quantity: $Line->Quantity";
echo"UnitPrice: $Line->UnitPrice";
}
}
?>
```

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: What issues did you have with your code ?

Comment: Lines are not displayed.

Comment: Please take an advantage of `print_r` method and display yourself a structure of `$Goods`.

Comment: yeah show use a `var_dump($xml)` (same as print_r, renders recursively an array)

Comment: print_r($xml) or var_dump($xml) displays data correctly, but the problem I still have is How can I assign values to variables? for example CardCode='V10000'; in PHP.